# Превращение Datetime2 типа данных в тип данных даты и времени привело к вне-диапазона значений

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Часть кода Create.cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreateDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">

            @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.CreateDate)
          .Name("datepicker")                
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:150px" })
            )

        </div>
    </div>
```

SlidersController.cs:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,SliderImage,CreateDate,HtmlContent")] Slider slider, HttpPostedFileBase imageFile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (imageFile != null && imageFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(imageFile.FileName);
                if (fileName != null)
                {
                    var extention = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                    var randomFileName = Path.GetRandomFileName() + extention;
                    slider.SliderImage = ImagePath + randomFileName;
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(ImagePath), randomFileName);
                    imageFile.SaveAs(path);
                    db.Sliders.Add(slider);
                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(slider);
    }
```

Model:

```
 public class Slider
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof (Resources.Resources), Name = "Slider_Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof (Resources.Resources), Name = "Slider_SliderImage")]
    public string SliderImage { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), Name = "Slider_CreateDate")]
    //[DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof (Resources.Resources), Name = "Slider_HtmlContent")]
    public string HtmlContent { get; set; }
}
```

Ошибка происходит при кнопке создании слайдера, как исправить ошибку

Comment: Ваши варианты..

Answer (score 1):

Что может быть вполне разумно, если учесть что `datetime2` имеет больший диапазон дат. `datetime2` имеет диапазон дат от "0001-01-01" до "9999-12-31", а `datetime` поддерживает года с 1753 по 9999.

Рискну предположить, что в момент вызова `await db.SaveChangesAsync();` `CreateDate` имеет значение, **год** которого **меньше 1753**... может быть `DateTime.MinValue`

Соответственно в SQL'ный `datetime` это значение не может быть записано.